# Why not using present perfect tense when it comes to since?

Tags: present-tense, perfect-aspect

1. "Aduhelm is the first novel therapy approved for Alzheimer’s disease since 2003."
2. On June 7th America's food and Drug adminstration approved the first drug since 2003 to treat Alzheimer's disease.

We have since in these two sentences, but why not use "has approved". ?
I dont understand because i thought when it comes to since, we have to use present perfect tense.

Answer (score 3):

You're parsing the first sentence incorrectly. *Aduhelm* in 1) is not something that therapy *approves* or *has approved*.

The sentence has a *reduced relative clause* and could also be written as:

> "Aduhelm is the first novel therapy [*which has been*] approved for Alzheimer’s disease since 2003."

In 2) it makes more sense to use the simple past tense *approved* instead of the past perfect tense *has approved* because the approval (for the drug) came on a certain date: June 7.

*Cambridge Dictionary* gives this useful bit on this distinction between the two tenses:

*Definite time in the past*

> We use the past simple to refer to definite time in the past (when we specify the time or how long) and usually with past time expressions such as yesterday, two weeks ago, last year, in 1995:

*We met in January 1975. We went to America together in 1978.*

**Not: We have met in January 1975. We have gone to America together in 1978.**

Comment: +1 for the reduced relative clause. Section 3, example 3 in this article describes this particular variety: http://random-idea-english.blogspot.com/2012/02/reduced-relative-clauses-lesson-and.html

Comment: It's less easy to see 'This is Elbonia's first win over Mordor since 1966' as a reduced relative. It's probably a reduced to-infinitival, if anything. 'First NP since [time phrase]' doesn't include a verb.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in British-English Books, "since" and "yet" are synonymous to Present Perfect.
But nowadays English that is seen all over the Internet and in Books or Movies aren't only British; they can be of any variant / dialect, and are (mostly) all standard English.

The second second has to do more with the usage of the tense rather than grammar.

The second sentence here just mentions a fact; there aren't any significant meanings to it rather than to provide some information.

Consider the following:

I lost my keys this morning. (And I am okay with that, no biggie)

I have lost my keys this morning. (And therefore I am standing here, locked out of my house)